# Struggling to vectorize brentq

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

How can I vectorize [`brentq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)? I would like to vectorize this function by iterating on K.

```py
from scipy.optimize import brentq

def fun(S, K, P, T, R, Q, Bin):
    def f(x): 
        return F(1, K/S, x, T, R, Q, Bin.get(K < S)) - P[K]/S
    return brentq(f, 0., 10.)
```

with

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def F(S, K, x, T, R, Q, B=Bin.get(K < S)):
    return B * (S * np.exp(-Q * np.ones_like(K) * T) * norm.cdf(B * S/K) 
                - np.exp(-R * np.ones_like(K) * T) * K * norm.cdf(B * S/K))
```

`S`, `K` are numpy arrays of same length.
`P` is a dictionary; its keys are the values of `K` and its values are floats.
`T`, `R`, `Q` are floats.
`Bin` is a dictionary that returns +/-1.

`fun` works well if I take single values instead of arrays.

I've tried to directly vectorize with:

```
K = np.linspace(50., 99., 100)
P = dict(zip(K, np.linspace(1, 10, 100)))
R = 0.
Q = 0.
T = 1.
S = 100. * np.ones_like(K)
Bin = {True: -1, False: 1}

np.vectorize(fun)(S, K, P, T, R, Q, Bin)
```

but it doesn't return the same result as a `for` loop like this:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(K)): 
    res.append(fun(S[i], K[i], P, T, T, Q, CP))
```

Edit : Find the solution with answers in comments, it now gives the same result, but indeed not faster than with a `for` loop...

Comment: [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) accepts an `excluded` argument to specify some inputs to not vectorize along, try adding `excluded={'T','R','Q','P','Bin'}`

Comment: Please, provide a [mre]. We don't need to have the actual code. But at least examples function whose signature are the same as the one involved.

Comment: Also, note that `np.vectorize` just automatize the creation of a for loop for you. Yet, it is still a for loop. A bit faster that a python for loop, because of the time gained in the iterations themselves (the cost of looping), but still, you'll end up with N calls to your `fun` function. It is not at all like if you were having numpy compute things by batch for your. That is why `np.vectorize` documentation clearly state that this function is not for performance purpose. You will not gain lot of computation time

Comment: (up to a factor 2, maybe, if the function itself is very simple; on the contrary nothing visible if the function is quite costly — again, only gain is on the iteration along vectors. Which has the cost of one or two additions. So, if `fun` cost not more than one or two addition itself, then that is not negligible before the remaining cost, the one of all those `fun` call. But if not, then what you gain is only some computation time on the easy part, but nothing in the heavy one)

Comment: You would gain way more if you could really vectorize your function. Typical gain I see here, when we remove the for loops from someone's code to use vectorization, is around factors 100, even 1000. But we can't do that, of course, without seeing the code. There is no generic way to vectorize (except for `np.vectorize`, which is not meant at all to be efficient)

Comment: `Bin` is a dictionary? `K < S` will produce a boolean vector if they are both vectors, so I'm not sure how you're trying to use that to index the dictionary.

Comment: @jared K and S are scalar, for now. So, a legit key to a dictionary. Tho, indeed, if find also suspicious to use a dictionary just to have a "False" and a "True" values.

Comment: Thank you for allr your answers. I believe my initial function f (the one which I have to find the root) is already vectorized since it is applicable to numpy arrays?

Comment: It's true that `f` can take `x` as a numpy arrays, but the `Bin` and `P`, which are arguments to `F` are not vectorized.

Comment: Part of the issue with your question is that `brentq` is inherently a scalar root finder. You can vectorized all the functions, but `brentq` will still not work. You should use something like `scipy.optimize.root`.

Comment: Note that `norm.cdf(B * S/K)` expression is duplicated so it is computed twice. This is sad since it is not only harder to read but also inefficient, especially since `cdf` is rather expensive AFAIK. Same for `np.one_like(K)` though this one is cheap.

Comment: If you can provide working code for the scalar case, I can likely provide code that allows you to solve the equation for many values of the parameters in a single vectorized call that *is* much faster. But right now your callable doesn't even depend on `x`, so it just returns a constant value. Please provide code with all imports that can be copy-pasted into a console and run, producing the desired result for a scalar case.